# How to add image background to pdf for every page?

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to set a background to a pdf and managed to set it with an image my pdf has a big table so the pages are added automatically not with the `Document.NewPage()` method so the image background is set only on the first page. This is the code that adds the background:

```
    Image backImg = Image.GetInstance(@"D:\websites\DIS\bugs\130208\A4.png");
    backImg.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
    backImg.Alignment = Image.UNDERLYING;

    var doc = new Document(pageSize);
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
    doc.Open();

    doc.Add(backImg);
    ...
    creating a big table
```

and not using the `doc.NewPage()` method. Do I have to loop throw every page and add the background image at the end before closing the doc, but how do I put it in the background not on top of the other elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you want to apply something to every page, you should use page events, more specifically [`PdfPageEvent.onEndPage(),`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPageEvent.html#onEndPage%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter,%20com.itextpdf.text.Document%29) to do it. You can find samples for its usage by keyword [Page events > onEndPage](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=220) --- these samples are taken from [iText in Action 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/). The samples mainly add footers and headers while you want to add background graphics.

Be aware that you shouldn't add content to the `Document` instance here but instead directly to the `PdfWriter,` and as you want the image to be under the page content , not above it, you will need to use `PdfWriter.getDirectContentUnder()` like in the sample [`Stationery`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=114) and not `PdfWriter.getDirectContent()` like in the other samples.

**PS:** The analogous samples for .Net can be found [here.](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx)

**PPS:** The sample [ImageDirect.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=70) / [ImageDirect.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter03&ex=ImageDirect) shows how to add an image to some direct content which might be the information missing here.

Comment: the documentation that you showed me is for java, my project is in c#

Comment: @XandrUu I added a link to the analogous .Net samples to the answer.

Comment: were exactly should I be looking because I didn't find anything useful

Comment: You should look at how to implement a PdfPageEvent class and use it to apply some change on every page of a document you create, e.g. adding the same background to each page in [Stationery.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter06&ex=Stationery); the only difference between your requirement and that sample is that the sample takes a page of another PDF as background while you only need an image.

Answer (score 0):

go for

> PdfPageEvent.onStartPage()

. In this event, write your code to insert the image (as you are doing it). What it will do is that as soon as a new page is created, it will add the image to it and then the content over it; giving a watermark effect.